# Android BLE onScanFailed with status 2 in Samsung phones

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am using Android BLE feature and following is my code.

I have created two callback methods(**onLeScan** and **ScanCallback**) as for android versions > KITKAT I am using **ScanCallback** and on or before KITKAT versions, I am using **onLeScan** callback.

```
// Implement BluetoothLeScanner for deprecation of onLeScan for Target android L // 25-12-14
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH && mBluetoothAdapter != null) {
                    mBluetoothLeScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
                    ScanSettings.Builder scanSettingsBuilder = new ScanSettings.Builder();
                    scanSettingsBuilder.setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY);
                    mScanSettings = scanSettingsBuilder.build();
                }

    if (mBluetoothAdapter != null && mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
                        if (mBluetoothLeScanner == null)
                            mBluetoothLeScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
                        mBluetoothLeScanner.startScan(new ArrayList<ScanFilter>(), mScanSettings, mScanCallback);
                    } else
                        mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                }
```

The issue is when scanning gets started, I am getting response in ***onScanFailed*** method with **status 2**.
Most of the phones in which I am facing this issue are Samsung phones.

How to achieve successful scanCallback?

Is it phone specific issue or general Bluetooth issue in Samsung phones?